# Ionic3 enviar SMS a número de Firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic, ionic3, sms

Buen día

Necesito enviar un sms tomando un número de un campo de la base de datos de firebase.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
//import { Profile } from '../../models/profile';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-controlpanel',
  templateUrl: 'controlpanel.html',
})
export class ControlpanelPage {

  
  profileData: Observable<any>;
  correo: String;
  message:any;
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private toast: ToastController,
    private sms: SMS,public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
    this.message = '55555555';
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if (data && data.email && data.uid) {
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Bienvenido to EVEREST GPS, /${data.email}`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();

        console.log('perfil/' + data.uid);
        this.afDatabase.object('perfil/' + data.uid).valueChanges().subscribe(action => {
          this.profileData = action["numbercel"];
 
        });

      }
      else {
        this.toast.create({
          message: 'Error de usuario o contraseña',
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      }

    })
  }
  send(){
    this.sms.send('3104444556', this.message)
      .then(()=>{
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Message send successfully',
          duration: 3000        });
        toast.present();
      },()=>{
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Failure',
          duration: 3000        });
        toast.present();
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Control Panel</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

  
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-content padding>
<ion-item>
<h1> {{profileData}}</h1>
</ion-item> 

<div text-center>
  <button ion-button (tap)="send()">Send</button>
    </div>
  
</ion-content>
```

Como hago para que en esta parte

send(){
        this.sms.send('31037448556', this.message)
          .then(()=>{

en vez del número pueda traer el campo que está desde firebase?
El número que está ahi se encuentra quemado, pero necesito traer el que ya me muestra desde la bd.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, no se como estará diseñado tu sistema, pero suponiendo que tengas un listado de contactos o clientes, deberías de tener dicho dato del teléfono en un array, ya sea desde un componente `maestro` o `maestro-detalle` debes de tenerlo almacenado y en caso de que el usuario de click en un botón de enviar mensaje solo harías uso de un evento en el cual le envias dicho parámetro; algo como: `send(numero_telefono){this.sms.send('numero_telefono', this.message)....etc}`, si es de este tipo, me lo haces saber y te doy mayor detalle.

Comment: Hola,
El número lo tengo almacenado en firebase lo traigo desde aqui

      console.log('perfil/' + data.uid);
        this.afDatabase.object('perfil/' + data.uid).valueChanges().subscribe(action => {
          this.profileData = action["numbercel"];

Comment: @jecorrales mira así lo tengo que trae el num desde firebase:
 console.log('perfil/' + data.uid);
 this.afDatabase.object('perfil/' + data.uid).valueChanges().subscribe(action => {
   this.profileData = action["numbercel"];
  });

Y para el envío de mensajes hice lo que me dijiste:

 send(numbercel){
this.sms.send(numbercel, this.message)
.then(()=>{
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
 message: 'Message send successfully',
duration: 3000        });
toast.present();
 },()=>{
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
message: 'Failure',
duration: 3000 });
  toast.present();})

Comment: si, eso lo tengo claro, voy tratar de hacerme entender: tienes un sistema donde traes los datos de un contaco o persona (su profile), supongamos que tienes 10 contactos diferentes (los recorres con un `*ngFor`) y hay un boton que dice `Send`, el cual debería de enviar un mensaje por defecto (o ¿hay algun campo habilitado para enviar un mensaje personalizado?) al teléfono que tenemos almacenado en la BD

Comment: Lo importante aquí es saber si te pintan o recorres de forma correcta los valores obtenidos por `http` al API de firebase. Ya teniendo eso podemos seguir, voy a tratar de abarcar y responder a tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

asumo que el objeto `profileData` contiene el numero de telefono lo unico que debe hacer es

```
send(){
this.sms.send(this.profileData.numeroTelefono, this.message)
  .then(()=>{
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Message send successfully',
      duration: 3000        });
    toast.present();
  },()=>{
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Failure',
      duration: 3000        });
    toast.present();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tratando de entender el funcionamiento de tu sistema, considerando la información suministrada:

Tienes un sistema de contacto, donde realizas una petición a la API de *Firebase* y obtienes los datos de una persona, por lo que procedemos a recorrer el array obtenido por la petición realizada:

Esto a modo de ejemplo del como sería la forma de realizar lo que esperas.

**Ionic View**

```
    <ion-list>
     <ion-item-group *ngFor="let contacto of listadoContactos">           
          <ion-avatar item-left><img [src]="'assets/contactos/'+contacto .foto_contacto+''"></ion-avatar>
          <h2>{{contacto.nombre_contacto}}</h2>
          <p>{{contacto.telefono_contacto}}</p>
          <button ion-item  text-left  (click)="cargarSMS(contacto)">
        </button>
      </ion-item-group>
    </ion-list>
```

**Typescript**

```
  public cargarSMS(contacto)
  {
    //Capturamos el valor del numero del contacto
    this.detalle_numero_contacto = contacto.numero_contacto;
    //Llamamos la funcion pertinente para enviar el contacto
    this.sendSMS(this.detalle_numero_contacto);
  }

  sendSMS(detalle_numero_contacto)
  {
   this.sms.send(this.detalle_numero_contacto, this.message)
     .then(()=>{
       let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
         message: 'Message send successfully',
         duration: 3000        });
       toast.present();
     },()=>{
       let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
         message: 'Failure',
         duration: 3000        });
        toast.present();
     });
  }
```

> **Nota:** Recuerda utilizar estas funcionalidades nativas en un entorno de producción (en tu celular de pruebas).

Puedes ver un ejemplo mucho más práctico y avanzado [en la documentación de Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#sliding-list) del como hacer una vista como lo que trato en el ejemplo.

**Ejemplo**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="img/slimer.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Slimer</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="left">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        Text
      </button>
      <button ion-button color="secondary">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
        Call
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
      <button ion-button color="primary">
        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
        Email
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

*Cualquier cosa, me haces saber si te ayudó o no.*